Wrap Two Text Elements in the same line when numberOfLines for one of the text elements is 2 - React Native
Problem
When trying to style two text elements, in which one of them needs to be displayed in two lines using the numberOfLines prop of the react-native Text element, the second text is not displayed as a continuation of the first one. Instead it is displayed on a new line.
Code Snippet that I tried:
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <Text numberOfLines={2}>
            Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url phone! Save to get a shareable url
          </Text>
          <Text>Something is coming after this</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 20
  },
  textContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
});

even after applying flexDirection: 'row' and flexWrap: 'wrap' the second text: 'Something is coming after this' is displayed on a new line.
You can see the output in the Image.
Image from Expo Output
Expected:

Expected result is to have the text: 'Something is coming after this' start right after the text: 'Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url phone! Save to get a shareable url' ends.
I want to achieve this using View instead of Wrapping it using Text Component.

